# In Google Form through app script, how to display question 2 with prefilled answer only when the user responded to question 1 correctly?

Tags: events, google-apps-script, google-forms, triggers

I would like to build a form which should have a question 1 to enter a code (which we have already shared to recipients for identification purpose) upon submitting the response code, a validation should perform and if it's successful, a question 2 with pre-filled answer should be displayed.

After the response code entered by user on the form for Question 1,

- How do I get the response code  provided by the user?
- How to validate it dynamically with the list of overall codes which I maintain in an excel?
- How to display the pre-filled question 2 with answer on the same form?

I have tried using App script through `onOpen` Form triggers, but didn't work out well.

`onOpen` Form Event trigger worked only when a form opened in an edit mode by form creator, but ideally we expected that it will trigger when the recipient who receives this link to fill the form opens it.

Any suggestions through App scripts also would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is too many questions for one post. I suggest you to structure them and take each step at a time - writing a post containing a single, well defined question and providing your efforts to achieve it yourself. As a small hint: You can create two forms - the first with the first question and on successful data validation and form submission the user will be redirected to the second form with the prefilled answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question

> After the response code entered by user on the form for Question 1,
>
> - How do I get the response code provided by the user?
> - How to validate it dynamically with the list of overall codes which I maintain in an excel?
> - How to display the pre-filled question 2 with answer on the same form?

Any of the above is possible by solely using Google Apps Script. One option is to  use a bookmarklet / web browser extension that handles userscripts to add that features to your Google Form but usually the practical solution by using Google Apps Script is to create a web application.